# Stretching the component in CSS to the full page width

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I have the following code: https://jsfiddle.net/u8db2j75/1/ and it works fine, I have the effect I wanted - a picture and some text next to it. But now I want to add another component, a navigation bar - and I want to add it on top of the page. So what I followed the example given here http://css-snippets.com/simple-horizontal-navigation/ and I created the code like this:

```
<div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="tutorials"><a class="active" href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li class="about"><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u8db2j75/2/ however, after modifying css as well -as you can see - the effect is far from what I expected... What did go wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your `.nav ul` and `.nav` a `min-width` of 100%.

Example:

```
.nav {
    min-width:100% !important;
}
.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u8db2j75/4/

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 50 reputation to comment the answer above, but:
List item needs to be displayed inline, or floated to the left so the result will be a horizontal navigation as per the examble shown in the issue.